# Error Inserting From Inner Join and EXCEPT clause SQL. conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Error:' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, except

I have 3 tables

Tabledocs2 
LogTable
Tabledocs1

I am trying to insert into Tabledocs2 from Tabledocs1 not in Tabledocs2 already.

The LogTable is the intermediate table which contains the columns of Tabledocs1 and Tabledocs2.

Convert on case doesn't catch/ handle this error. 
" conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Error:' to data type int"

```
PRINT 'INSERTING FROM Tabledocs2 INTO Tabledocs1'
        INSERT INTO Tabledocs1 (Log_id, document_name , document_icon , document_body )
        SELECT  CONVERT(INT, CASE WHEN IsNumeric(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),ID)) = 1 then CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ID) else 0 End) as int  , document_name , document_icon , document_body 
        FROM LogTable
        INNER JOIN Tabledocs1 
        ON LogTable.detail_ID  = Tabledocs1.detail_ID 
        AND log_ID = @LogID 
        EXCEPT
        (SELECT Log_id, document_name , document_icon , document_body FROM Tabledocs2)--To Avoid duplicates
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should convert in the other direction?

```
INSERT INTO Tabledocs1 (Log_id, document_name , document_icon , document_body )
    SELECT ID, document_name , document_icon , document_body 
    FROM LogTable INNER JOIN
         Tabledocs1 
         ON LogTable.detail_ID  = Tabledocs1.detail_ID 
    WHERE log_ID = @LogID 
    EXCEPT
    (SELECT CAST(Log_id as VARCHAR(12)), document_name , document_icon , document_body
     FROM Tabledocs2
    );--To Avoid duplicates
```

There may be reasons -- such as leading zeros -- why you would want to convert to a numeric format.  However, 12 characters is too long for an integer, so you would need `NUMERIC()` or `BIGINT` anyway.

Comment: Log_id is integer,
document_name is varchar(20),
document_icon , document_body  are binary. I'll try with NUMERIC()

Answer (score 1):

`isnumeric()` can be misleading. In sql server 2012+ use `try_convert()` instead. It will return `null` for failed conversions instead of an error.

```
print 'INSERTING FROM Tabledocs2 INTO Tabledocs1'
insert into Tabledocs1 (
    Log_id
  , document_name
  , document_icon
  , document_body
 )
select 
    coalesce(try_convert(int,ID),0)
  , document_name
  , document_icon
  , document_body
from LogTable
  inner join Tabledocs1 
    on LogTable.detail_ID = Tabledocs1.detail_ID 
    and log_ID = @LogID
except
 select 
    Log_id
  , document_name
  , document_icon
  , document_body
 from Tabledocs2
```